# How to set the automation properties of a DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: uwp, accessibility, windows-community-toolkit

Is the only way to set the automation properties of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` to inherit it in a new control and override the AutomationPeer?

Considering the following, I end up with two entries in the UI tree.

- one for the `FontIcon`, that's contained within
- one for the `DataGridCell`

```xml
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Symbol">
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:SampleOrder">
                <FontIcon
                    AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind SymbolName}"
                    Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="{x:Bind Symbol}" />
            </DataTemplate> 
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I can set AutomationProperties on the `FontIcon` but there doesn't appear to be a way to stop the control rendering a "custom" container element with a null/empty name.

For clarification, here's the UI Automation Tree that includes the "custom" container for the cell.
[image: partial screenshot of UIATree showing empty custom container]

Such output does not meet basic accessibility requirements (specifically section 508 502.3.1).

The custom value comes from [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/d1c9e732256942c06d65d1ba8ba96015f215c394/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/Automation/DataGridCellAutomationPeer.cs#L80) but there doesn't seem to be a way to change this without subclassing.

Being forced to derive a custom control just to be able to set basic accessibility properties seems unnecessary. Is there an easier way?

*Aside: I know that in the screenshot the Globe text is incorrectly listed as a 'group' but I know how to fix that. It's separate to the question I'm asking.*

---

**UPDATE**

I asked the original question (above) before attempting to see if subclassing was possible. It's not as the necessary classes are sealed. :(

Comment: Hello, do you mean that `FontIcon` is not displayed when Symbol is empty? If you have any questions about the automation properties output of `DataGridTemplateColumn`, you can open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/new/choose)

Comment: The Community Toolkit GitHub site specifically says to "post your question on Stack Overflow ...  Otherwise, this issue will be automatically closed"

Comment: Hello, sorry for not explaining clearly. For general usage questions, you can ask on StackOverflow, but from the description of your question, DataGridTemplateColumn seems to lack support for the automation properties of the inside controls. If the current general settings do not work, you can choose to derive a custom Control, or submit a feature request on Github (feature request needs to be submitted on Github).